How can I make lines break automatically in table?
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Juan Da Silva}
\lhead{Machine Learning}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\lfoot{TUM}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying


\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt}

% Plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, ext.paths.ortho, backgrounds, fit, calc}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    {\centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        hlines,
        vlines,
        colspec={ccc}, 
    }
        Type & Max pooling & \SetCell[p, width=4cm]{2-2} Average pooling \\
        Purpose & Each pooling operation selects the maximum value of the current view & \SetCell[p, width=4cm]{2-3} Each pooling operation averages the values of the current view \\
        % Illustration & \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{images/max-pooling.jpg} &         \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{images/average-pooling.jpg}
    \end{tblr}
    \par}

    
\end{document}


c doesn't break. You want something like p{<width>} or m{<width>}, but tblr probably has more specialist column types, too. Please remove extraneous code from your example. There is no need for people to load TikZ or pgfplots and a bunch of libraries for this. But please add the code required to compile.

Why don't you use the Q type column with a width argument as follows:  colspec={ccQ[wd=4cm]}. X type columns would also be an anlternative if you want to make sure that the table automatically occupies the entire textwidth.

Your syntax for \SetCell isn't correct. The optional argument should specify how many rows and columns the table should span, e.g.[r=2,c-2] and the mandatory argument can have options for the cell like the width, e.g. {4cm}

@leandriis I used the X type columns. If I add a new row containing in the first column text and the other columns figures (as in the commented line), how do I make the text to be vertical aligned?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

The answers to this question might be helpful too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/611617/114006

Any news? You receive two answers, You got two answers. It would be nice if you accept one of them (by clicking on the check mark at answer's top left side) that best solves your problem. As I see, so far you not accept any answer which you got on your questions. Why?

An alternative solution with use \adjincludegraphics of adjustbox package:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
\adjustboxset{width=0.15\textwidth,
              margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt,
              valign=c
              }
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,
             colspec={cX[m,j]X[m,j]}, 
             row{Z} = {c}
             }
Type    & Max pooling   
            & Average pooling \\
Purpose & Each pooling operation selects the maximum value of the current view 
            & Each pooling operation averages the values of the current view    \\
Illustration 
        & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a} 
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}


An example with a flexible width X and a fixed with Q column type with left aligned and vertically centered contents:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent
    \begin{tblr}{
        hlines,
        vlines,
        colspec={cX[m]Q[m,wd=4cm]}, 
    }
        Type & Max pooling & Average pooling \\
        Purpose & Each pooling operation selects the maximum value of the current view & Each pooling operation averages the values of the current view \\
         Illustration & \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image} &         \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image}
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}

